How to drag & down the description(info)
Input:



Id
Unit No
Tenant Name
Net Rent
Security Deposit




1
#k1-30
Kkks Pte Ltd
12.4
115000.12


2


14.4



3


16.4



4
#K1-40
crown Pte Ltd
22.60
215000.12


5


24.60



6


26.60



7
#K14-01
Techno pv Ltd
64.60
124230.12


8


27.60



9
#K14-13
Gardening
26.80
21231.12


10
#k11-12

26.80
128237.12



Output:



Id
Unit No
Tenant Name
Net Rent
Security Deposit




1
#k1-30
Kkks Pte Ltd
12.4
115000.12


2
#k1-30
Kkks Pte Ltd
14.4
115000.12


3
#k1-30
Kkks Pte Ltd
16.4
115000.12


4
#K1-40
crown Pte Ltd
22.60
215000.12


5
#K1-40
crown Pte Ltd
24.60
215000.12


6
#K1-40
crown Pte Ltd
26.60
215000.12


7
#K14-01
Techno pv Ltd
64.60
124230.12


8
#K14-01
Techno pv Ltd
27.60
124230.12


9
#K14-13
Gardening
26.80
21231.12


10
#k11-12
Gardening
26.80
128237.12



In SQL Server, I have to drag and down the unit number, tenant name and security deposits. BUT I HAVE ONLY UNIQUE COLUMN as [UNIT No].
In this scenario, There should be same tenant name but different unit number is possible.
But the id no 9 and 10 having merged tenant name so it could be a same tenant name.

You'll be wanting a window function

Relational databases aren't spreadsheets. You can't "drag down" values as there's no implied order in a table.
SQL works on sets of data. You can repeat values, calculate ranks and aggregates within a specific set using Window functions.
First, you need to identify the "ranges" or windows of rows where you want to repeat values. You can do that using count(UnitNo) OVER(ORDER BY ID) as RangeID. This orders rows by ID and counts only the non-null values as it goes down the set.
The query :
select count(UnitNo) OVER(ORDER BY ID) as RangeID, * 
from ThatTable

Produces :
RangeID Id  UnitNo  TenantName  NetRent SecurityDeposit
1       1   #k1-30  Kkks Pte Ltd    12.40   115000.12
1       2   NULL    NULL    14.40   NULL
1       3   NULL    NULL    16.40   NULL
2       4   #K1-40  crown Pte Ltd   22.60   215000.12
2       5   NULL    NULL    24.60   NULL
2       6   NULL    NULL    26.60   NULL
3       7   #K14-01 Techno pv Ltd   64.60   124230.12
3       8   NULL    NULL    27.60   NULL

Once you have the ranges, you can repeat the first value of each range with FIRST_VALUE.
The query :
;with ranges as (
    select count(UnitNo) OVER(ORDER BY ID) as RangeID, * 
    from ThatTable
)
select 
    RangeID,
    ID,
    FIRST_VALUE(UnitNo)OVER(PARTITION BY RangeID Order by ID) as UnitNo, 
    FIRST_VALUE(TenantName)OVER(PARTITION BY RangeID Order by ID) as TenantName, 
    NetRent, 
    FIRST_VALUE(SecurityDeposit)OVER(PARTITION BY RangeID Order by ID) as SecurityDeposit
from ranges

Returns :
RangeID ID  UnitNo  TenantName  NetRent SecurityDeposit
1   1   #k1-30  Kkks Pte Ltd    12.40   115000.12
1   2   #k1-30  Kkks Pte Ltd    14.40   115000.12
1   3   #k1-30  Kkks Pte Ltd    16.40   115000.12
2   4   #K1-40  crown Pte Ltd   22.60   215000.12
2   5   #K1-40  crown Pte Ltd   24.60   215000.12
2   6   #K1-40  crown Pte Ltd   26.60   215000.12
3   7   #K14-01 Techno pv Ltd   64.60   124230.12
3   8   #K14-01 Techno pv Ltd   27.60   124230.12

The column NetRent doesn't use FIRST_VALUE because we want to retain its values. We can use ISNULL to use the first value only if the column doesn't have its own value:
select 
    RangeID,
    ID,
    ...
    ISNULL(NetRent,FIRST_VALUE(TenantName)OVER(PARTITION BY RangeID Order by ID)) as NetRent, 
    ...
from ranges


data
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Id                 INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,UnitNo          VARCHAR(80)
  ,TenantName      VARCHAR(50)
  ,NetRent         NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL
  ,SecurityDeposit NUMERIC(9,2)
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(Id,UnitNo,TenantName,NetRent,SecurityDeposit) VALUES 
(1,'#k1-30','Kkks Pte Ltd',12.4,115000.12),
(2,NULL,NULL,14.4,NULL),
(3,NULL,NULL,16.4,NULL),
(4,'#K1-40','crown Pte Ltd',22.60,215000.12),
(5,NULL,NULL,24.60,NULL),
(6,NULL,NULL,26.60,NULL),
(7,'#K14-01','Techno pv Ltd',64.60,124230.12),
(8,NULL,NULL,27.60,NULL);

use need coalesce,max with window functions and subquery  as follows
select
Id,
coalesce([UnitNo], max([UnitNo]) over (partition by [UnitNo1])) as [UnitNo1],
coalesce([TenantName], max([TenantName]) over (partition by [TenantName1])) as [TenantName1],
NetRent,  
coalesce([SecurityDeposit], max([SecurityDeposit]) over (partition by [SecurityDeposit1])) as [SecurityDeposit1]
  
from (
select t.*,
max(case when [UnitNo] is not null then Id end) over (order by Id) as [UnitNo1],
max(case when [TenantName] is not null then Id end) over (order by Id) as [TenantName1],
max(case when [SecurityDeposit] is not null then Id end) over (order by Id) as [SecurityDeposit1]
 
from mytable t
) t

or in order to update use CTE in query
;with t as
(
select
Id,UnitNo,TenantName,NetRent,SecurityDeposit,
coalesce([UnitNo], max([UnitNo]) over (partition by [UnitNo1])) as [UnitNo1],
coalesce([TenantName], max([TenantName]) over (partition by [TenantName1])) as [TenantName1],
coalesce([SecurityDeposit], max([SecurityDeposit]) over (partition by [SecurityDeposit1])) as [SecurityDeposit1]
  
from (
select t.*,
max(case when [UnitNo] is not null then Id end) over (order by Id) as [UnitNo1],
max(case when [TenantName] is not null then Id end) over (order by Id) as [TenantName1],
max(case when [SecurityDeposit] is not null then Id end) over (order by Id) as [SecurityDeposit1]
from mytable t
) t
  
)

update t
set UnitNo=[UnitNo1],
    TenantName=[TenantName1],
    SecurityDeposit=SecurityDeposit1


select * from mytable


dbfiddle
